# Why am I penalized for someone removing his own answer?

Tags: support

My reputation log indicates that I have received a -1 because LPChip has removed his own answer in "[How do I extract an archive embedded inside a video when WinRAR can't detect it?](https://superuser.com/q/1172618/477799)" Okay, I can understand someone retracting his or her answer, but why am I penalized?

[image: My daily log]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Why am I penalized?

> My reputation log indicates that I have received a -1 because LPChip has removed his own answer

**Before the answer was deleted:**

- You gained 2 rep when you had an edit approved on the answer.
- You lost 1 rep because you downvoted the answer.

That leaves a net gain of 1 rep.

**After the answer was deleted:**

- You lost the 2 rep that you gained when you had an edit approved on the answer.
- You regained the 1 rep that you lost because you downvoted the answer.

That leaves a net loss of 1 rep.

Note:

- The reputation log is not showing the -2 for the edit. Instead it is showing the aggregate -1 for the removed - which is correct - as it's not broken down as +1 -2.

See [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) for more information.

Comment: ah hah! I missed that downvote getting reversed. I was wondering why *one* rep.

Comment: @DavidPostill That's not correct. I reality, my log indicates that I have received -1 for the downvote, -1 for the removal, +2 for the edit. As a result I have a net total of 0 reputation. Of course, my question was focused on the -1 for removal alone, but since you bring the others up...

Comment: @FleetCommand It's not showing the -2 for the edit. Instead it is showing the aggregate -1 for the removed - which is correct - as it's not broken down as +1 -2.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for the system to tell the difference between an edit for an edit's sake, and a edit that made a question a lot better.

Considering your comment - it seemed you felt the answer wasn't *good enough* and was *factually incorrect*, and that comment might have convinced the OP to delete.

So yeah, the system worked as designed, since once deleted, no one actually benefits from the edits you did, which are intended to encourage people to improve good posts to make them better, or at least fix things.